# BeautifulSoup extract data within a div

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I've browsed the previous questions for an hour and tried various solutions but I can't get this to work. I've extracted the results I want from a website, now I just have to mine these divs for the specific information I want.

The results are isolated like so:

```
items=soup.findAll(id=re.compile("itembase"))
```

For each item, I want to extract for example the lat and long from this piece of html:

```
<div id="itembase29" class="result-item -result unselected clearfix even" data-
part="fl_base" data-lat="51.9006" data-lon="-8.51008" data-number="29" 
is-local="true" data-customer="32060963" data-addrid="1" 
data-id="4b00fae498e3cc370133e8a14fd75160">
<div class="arrow">
</div>
```

How do I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Pass your html object into beautiful soup.

   ```
   soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
   ```
2. Find the div.

   ```
   div = soup.div
   ```
3. Get the attributes you're looking for from the div.

   ```
   lat, lon = div.attrs['data-lat'], div.attrs['data-lon']
   ```
4. Print.

   ```
   >>> print lat, lon
   51.9006 -8.51008
   ```

I left the `.attrs` method in there for clarity, but in more general terms, you can access the attributes of *any* element like a dictionary, you don't even really need the `.attrs` method, like so:  `div['data-lon']`.  This obviously doesnt work over a list of `div`s, you need to iterate over the list.

```
for div in divs:
    print div['data-lon'], div['data-lat']
```

Or list comprehension.

```
[(div['data-lon'], div['data-lat']) for div in divs]
```

Comment: Thanks. This now works: for item in items:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(str(item))
    div = soup.div
    print div['data-lon'],div['data-lat']