# R - Extracting data within a div

Tags: html, r, parsing, attributes

I'm working on R and I would like to extract data from the code of a page and transform it in a dataframe. I think that what I would like to do is close to this one ([BeautifulSoup extract data within a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13365996/beautifulsoup-extract-data-within-a-div)) but if possible, I'd like to do it with R.

Here is the code which interests me:

```
<div class="item clearfix" artist="Georges" song="Melody" ...>
<div class="item clearfix" artist="Leonard" song="Inspiration" ...>
<div class="item clearfix" artist="Bill" song="Gold" ...>
```

I would like to have it as:

[image: Data Frame]

Most examples I read are trying to get the text between   Text  but my problem is a bit different and I do not really know from where I should begin.

Comment: Take a look at the rvest package.  The html_nodes and html_attr functions should be what you are looking for.

Comment: Please provide the code for the attempt that you've made thusfar. As SO is not a code writing service, we ask you to provide a minimal, complete, verifiable example of your code and the problem that you've run into.

Comment: You have not provided a URL which means there is a high likelihood that you're attempting to violate some site's Terms of Service. Paste the URL and show some R code you've tried that didn't work or consider deleting your question. Also, pictures are for plots, not data or code.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for your help. I would have post some code if I had any but as I said, I didn't know where to start, the package/function to use.

Following the insights given by Dave2e, I could solve my problem. Here is the code:

```
info <- read_html(url) %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@class="item clearfix"]') %>% xml_attr("artist")
```