# Finding the value in a div beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm new to beautifulsoup and I'm trying to scrape the price for the car. The issue with the price is it comes back 2 values in the div tag. At the moment I was able to find the rest of the attributes but I cant seem to find the price.

MY CODE(loops through the div tag and finds the specific attribute for the car)

```
import requests, lxml.html, csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = requests.get("https://www.carsireland.ie/used-cars/bmw")
content = url.content
pri = lxml.html.fromstring(url.content)
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
rows = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "listing__details listing__details--desktop"})



# write headers

for row in rows:
    carname = row.find('h2').text.strip()
    carlocation = row.find('div', {"class": "listing__details-location"}).text.strip()
    carmileage = row.find('div', {"class": "listing__details-data-mileage"}).text.strip()
    carcolour = row.find('div', {"class": "listing__details-color"}, 'p').text.strip()
    caryear = row.find('div', {"class": "listing__details-data-year"}, 'p').text.strip()
    carprice = row.find('div', {"class": "listing__details-private-seller"}).find_previous()

    print(carprice)
```

This is the HTML code for rows, This is the div I used to locate the other attributes.

```
<div class="listing__details listing__details--desktop">
<div class="listing__details-location">
          Meath
        </div>
<div class="listing__details-vehicle">
<h2>BMW 316</h2>
<p>316I ES Z3SQ 4DR E90 SALOON N45 1.6</p>
</div>
<div class="listing__details-data">
<div class="listing__details-data-year">
<p>2007</p>
</div>
<div class="listing__details-data-mileage">
                      309 km 
                  </div>
</div>
<div class="listing__details-pricing">
                      €900
                                <div class="listing__details-private-seller">Private</div>
</div>
<div class="listing__details-color">
<span class="" style="background-color: black;"></span>
<p>BLACK</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BeautifulSoup extract data within a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13365996/beautifulsoup-extract-data-within-a-div)

Comment: @Benjamin Waife this line may help ```row.find('div', {"class": "listing__details-pricing"}).string```

Comment: Hi @iliya It's printing some of the values but not all of them

Comment: @Benjamin Waife what is the output?

Comment: There are 12 cars I'm trying to scrape it will print half of them. Someone else solved my issue thank you helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `re` module to get exactly number or `strings` attribute, which returns generator:

```
import re

# ...

for row in rows:
    price = float(re.sub("[^0-9\.]", "", row.find('div', {"class": "listing__details-pricing"}).text))
    print(price) # returns 900

    # or

    price = next(row.find('div', {"class": "listing__details-pricing"}).strings).strip()
    print(price) # returns "€900"
```

Comment: Yes, this is working thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Use class: "listing__details-pricing" instead of class: "listing__details-private-seller" to get carprice

Modified code:

```
for row in rows:
    carname = row.find('h2').text.strip()
    carlocation = row.find('div', {"class": "listing__details-location"}).text.strip()
    carmileage = row.find('div', {"class": "listing__details-data-mileage"}).text.strip()
    carcolour = row.find('div', {"class": "listing__details-color"}, 'p').text.strip()
    caryear = row.find('div', {"class": "listing__details-data-year"}, 'p').text.strip()
    carprice = row.find('div', {"class": "listing__details-pricing"}).text.strip().split(' ')[0].strip()

    print(carprice)
```